# T - SQL statement for number ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Create table temp
(
ID nvarchar(50)
)
```

ID contains numeric values prevailing zeros in some cases so it is defined as varchar

How to get values starts with 3555 to 3999 and 8000 to 9999.There is no specific rule that length is always 4. 
Eg:

```
3555 
35688888888888
3590909

8000
85805667
```

all of the values are valid and are to be fetched.

Please let me know T- SQL statement for the above scenario

Comment: What are you looking for exactly? You have the table and you want to retrieve the data? You want to generate the data in the table? Or .. ?

Comment: what have you tried? the `LIKE` operator or the `LEFT` and `SUBSTRING` functions may do what you need

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use few expressions with [`LIKE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx). If you have an index on `ID`, it would use it, so it will be efficient. Something like this:

```
SELECT
    ID
FROM
    temp
WHERE
    ID LIKE '3[5-9]%'
    OR ID LIKE '[89]%'
```

`LIKE '3[5-9]%'` matches any string that starts with `3` and which second character is `5` or `6` or `7` or `8` or `9`. After these two characters there can be 0 or more other characters. Any number of extra characters.

`LIKE '[89]%'` matches any string that starts with `8` or `9` and any number characters after.

Comment: Hi range is from 3555 and beyond.. can you please let me know how to achieve it

Comment: @user2545157, the current answer should work for any length of the value. the `%` matches any number of characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the first four chars, convert that to a number and query like this:

```
SELECT
  [ID]
FROM temp
WHERE convert(int,LEFT([ID],4)) BETWEEN 3500 AND 3999
OR convert(int,LEFT([ID],4)) BETWEEN 8000 AND 9999
```

For lots of data this will be horribly slow, so if you need performance I would recommend to add an indexed `int` column to the table where you store the number that represents the first four digits of `ID`.